# shell command not executing using c# on IIS server

Tags: c#, shell, iis, command-prompt, autodesk

```
                        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        cmd.Start();
                        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("@echo off");
                        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo.");
                        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(".\\lmutil.exe" + " lmstat -S adskflex -c xxxx@192.168.xx.xx > " + Server.MapPath("Status.txt"));
                        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo.");
                        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo.");
                        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("pause");
                        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
                        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
                        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
                        cmd.WaitForExit();
```

This code fetches a **status.txt** from *AutoDesk licence server* and save it to the current directory. Each time **status.txt** gets updated.
All works good on the localhost but not on the main server.

On the real IIS server **status.txt** does not update. When I open cmd on the server and execute this command it says

> cant find lmutil.exe

even if in the same directory where all code resides.
All the problem I got by moving to server from localhost...

Comment: Is there any reason you don't start lmutil.exe directly, instead of calling cmd and passing data to the stdin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to figure  what your .\ path on the server is? lets assume you run your tool as the user on the local machine and your path will mostlikely be the path where the exe of your tool is. If you run it on the other machine for example as a admin (elevated cmd prompt) you might end up on a location that is not quite the .\ you expect.

So try use something like

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDir like

```
 FileInfo fi = New FileInfo($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDir}\\lmutil.exe");
 if(fi.Exisits)
 {
   //do something with your tool
 }
```

to figure out where your application really lives and to get the lmutil.exe in that directory.

**Update based on Comments:**

it seems you just want to update a file in your DocumentRoot on the IIS so easiest way to go is put your tool on the server and run it there. If you cant put it on the server you still need to make sure you can access the status.txt on the IIS and copy the lnutil.exe to the machine you want to run your app from ( i guess thats what you do for testing).

**Update for Server.MapPath**

This will give you the path on the server for example C:\inet\mysite\bin\lmutil.exe but if you run your app on a different machine it doesnt mean this path exixst there. The code you runing is aiming on a local path so if you run the lmutil on the server you need to figure out how to invoke the call for the lmutil.exe on the remote location!

Comment: i dont think its problem with the path bcs i tried it with tried it with Server.MapPath("lmutil.exe"); but not working

Comment: i dont know about server.mappath but you wanted to be able to call an executable in the basedir of your application so thats what this line above trying to provide. A path to this appalivation. put the path in a FileInfo and check if it exists and if so you should be able to call that executable

Comment: Server.MapPath() gives the absolute path like C://xx/xx/xx/xx.exe and in fileinfo it shows the same path

Comment: is the path the path you expect the tool to be , do you have permissions to run it? you onyl use Server.MapPath for you status.txt not for the lmutil.exe so your error shows it cant find lmutil.exe and the example i gave you shows how to check if ylmutil.exe lives in the same path then you application lives. No more and no less.

Comment: as far as i understand mappath it would map a url to a physical path on the server but you dont need that to begin with if you running your app on the same server. If not you have to make sure you have permission to reach the physical path  meaning you need to make sure you can access lmutil.exe from your document root on the server. I dont know about IIS but i am pretty sure there are some safeguard regarding executables.

Comment: i got the solution . as you said problem was in permission to execute that file . by adding `cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";//runs command prompt as administrator` runs cmd as administrator and its working nice

Comment: and also used `Server.MapPath("")` for both the file to get absolute path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203800/discussion-between-parthraj-panchal-and-markus-rosjat).

Answer (score 0):

try to specify full path into configuration `lmutil.exe`

Comment: tried it with Server.MapPath("lmutil.exe"); but not working

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. While you don't meet the required [50 reputation to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) I urge you to answer self explanatory questions before posting a comment as a question, as this will garner downvotes and make it harder for you to reach the 50 rep minimum